# Customizing the wp_video_shortcode output with add_filter

Tags: functions, filters, shortcode, block-editor, request-filter

I am trying to add `onmouseover="this.play()" onmouseout="this.pause()"` to the default `<video` element in Wordpress. I am using Gutenberg block editor.

By default, this is what the output from the video block looks like in HTML:

```
<video src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/sample-video.mp4"></video>
```

I want it to be like this:

```
<video onmouseover="this.play()" onmouseout="this.pause()" src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/sample-video.mp4"></video>
```

I want to add the `onmouseover="this.play()" onmouseout="this.pause()"` to the default video element.

I have tried the below filter but it's not working:

```
add_filter( 'wp_video_shortcode', function( $output ) {
    $output = str_replace( '<video', '<video onmouseover="this.play()" onmouseout="this.pause()"', $output );
    return $output;
} );
```

Am I doing something wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: That looks like it should work. Where are you adding the code? Is it in a plugin or in your active theme's `functions.php` file?

Comment: I don’t believe the video block uses the shortcode. It would have its own output. So I don’t think this filter will help.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed the Gutenberg note.

Comment: So, I guess because we are using the Gutenberg Video blog, the shortcode won't work anymore? Is there any workaround to this? How can we modify the output of the Gutenberg Video Block? 

I tried looking for any info regarding this in the official WordPress documentation but so far, nothing useful.

Comment: You might need to dig in to the [Block Editor (ie, Gutenberg) Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/).

Comment: That didn't help much. Ended up going the JavaScript way. As far as I know, there is no native way to do this right now in WordPress.